# Data export in word table adding a subtotal row

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-word

I export data from a DataGridView to a Word table.

E.g.:

```
Amount | Number | Name | Unit price | Sum

3      | 0815   | test | 1,50       | 4,50
```

This works fine.
But if I have so many positions that a page break occurs, I automatically want to insert (at the end of the page) an extra row with the sum of all positions on that page.

How can I do this??

Here is how I actually export the data

```
      for (int r = 0; r < dg.Rows.Count; r++)
      {
          oTable.Cell(j, 1).Range.Text = iPos.ToString();
          oTable.Cell(j, 2).Range.Text = Number.ToString();
          oTable.Cell(j, 3).Range.Text = Name.ToString();
          oTable.Cell(j, 4).Range.Text = UnitPrice.ToString();
          oTable.Cell(j, 5).Range.Text = Sum.ToString();
          j += 3;
          iPos++;
      }
```

Comment: Is the number of rows per page constant or variable?

Comment: The number of rows per page is variable

Comment: This is not an easy task. I would advice you to assign fixed size to your rows and other elements on your report so that you know where the page break is.

Comment: Ok, that's what I have almost thought. Now if I have a fix number of rows, how can I insert a row?

Answer (score 0):

This code will calculate subtotals after every 10 and insert them:

```
 var subTotal = 0;
 for (int r = 0; r < dg.Rows.Count; r++)
  {
      oTable.Cell(j, 1).Range.Text = iPos.ToString();
      oTable.Cell(j, 2).Range.Text = Number.ToString();
      oTable.Cell(j, 3).Range.Text = Name.ToString();
      oTable.Cell(j, 4).Range.Text = UnitPrice.ToString();
      oTable.Cell(j, 5).Range.Text = Sum.ToString();
      j += 3;
      iPos++;

     //Every 10th row is a subtotal (because you do 3 row jumps j+=3)  
     subtotal+=Sum;
     if ((j % 3 * 10) == 0) {
           var currentRow = oTable.Rows[j];
           //Insert after this row
           var subtotalRow = oTable.Rows.Add(currentRow)
           subtotalRow.Cells[5].Range.Text = subtotal.ToString();
           subtotal = 0;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
But I get the following error: Cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of type "Word.Rows".
Error occurs:  var currentRow = oTable.Rows[j];
Same error message for Cells.

Comment: try `Item(x)`  instead if `[x]`